# Uncaught TypeError: this.getExtraNgModuleProviders is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, angular7, jit

I am working on a repository that keeps throwing this error on the console:
`Uncaught TypeError: this.getExtraNgModuleProviders is not a function`.

The projects compiles fine on "ng serve" but it shows a blank page and that error on the console. I have tried many things but I couldn't find a way out.

I have tried uninstalling and installing @angular/compiler but didn't work. The problem seems to be with JitCompiler not finding `this.getExtraNgModuleProviders`

I think the function `this.getExtraNgModuleProviders` in the JitCompiler should be `this._getExtraNgModuleProviders` instead on the compiler.js. Since all the functions around it seem to include the underscore.

UPDATE:

I don't think the function name has anything to do with it since other developers can run the project fine and they have the same Jit compiler.js file. For reference: This is where it takes me when I click the error on the console

```
 function JitCompiler(_metadataResolver, _templateParser, _styleCompiler, _viewCompiler, _ngModuleCompiler, _summaryResolver, _reflector, _compilerConfig, _console, getExtraNgModuleProviders) {
            this._metadataResolver = _metadataResolver;
            this._templateParser = _templateParser;
            this._styleCompiler = _styleCompiler;
            this._viewCompiler = _viewCompiler;
            this._ngModuleCompiler = _ngModuleCompiler;
            this._summaryResolver = _summaryResolver;
            this._reflector = _reflector;
            this._compilerConfig = _compilerConfig;
            this._console = _console;
            this.getExtraNgModuleProviders = getExtraNgModuleProviders;//<- error is pointed here
            this._compiledTemplateCache = new Map();
            this._compiledHostTemplateCache = new Map();
            this._compiledDirectiveWrapperCache = new Map();
            this._compiledNgModuleCache = new Map();
            this._sharedStylesheetCount = 0;
            this._addedAotSummaries = new Set();
        }
```

All other developers have the same compiler.js as mine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this.getExtraNgModuleProviders is not a function, maybe your "this" on this function call is passing another scope

Comment: Hey, @VitorPiovezam I am not sure what you mean. But `this.getExtraNgModuleProviders` is a function call that is performed by JitCompiler on compiler.js. I didn't do anything to the compiler.js so I am not sure how that is possible.

Comment: This method is defined in `https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser-dynamic/src/compiler_factory.ts` so ensure that you have `platform-browser-dynamic npm package` installed. One option is to delete the node_modules folder and then install run `npm install` command to install packages again

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I sensed that was the problem (not having platform-browser-dynamic) but I used `npm i @angular/platform-browser-dynamic` and it still didn't work. I will try out deleting the whole node_modules folder and will update.

Comment: compiler.js is the same so the problem -  I guess -  is in your local project. Try delete your package-lock file, node_modules folder, and run ```$ npm cache clean --force``` and ```$ npm install```.

Comment: @VitorPiovezam That didn't seem to work either unfortunately

Comment: @AndrewGeorge did you solve the issue? I'm stuck with the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did the following and the error was resolved. It is because of version incompatibility of your @angular/platform-browser-dynamic.

```
npm uninstall @angular/platform-browser-dynamic

npm install @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your angular/platform-browser-dynamic not updated. Change in your package.json like this;

```
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0"
```

after delete node modules and run "npm install" .

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error message. We are using .net core with angular.

`ng build` worked flawless, however starting from VS threw the `Uncaught TypeError: this.getExtraNgModuleProviders is not a function` exception.

I could fix this with a new clone of our repo, probably something in the VS cache caused the issue.